# Spirit Boost real_p parser behaving strangely

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a following problem: I am reusing old code that uses real_p parser to parse real numbers. I would like to capture each number, convert it to string, and put it in vector of strings.
I am using the following code, where l_double is a variable of the type double, convertdouble function converts a double to a string, and result.m_literalValues is the vector of strings.
However, the code will not assign a parsed value to l_double.

```
rule<> alternative3 =   +(real_p        [assign_a(l_double)]
                                        [push_back_a(result.m_LiteralValues, convertdouble(l_double))]
                                        >>  str_p(",")
                            )
```

Does anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Note: I will not re-engineer the old code, which is much more complex than the example given. I just want to extract the strings of all values parsed, and to put them in the vector of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be located in `push_back_a(result.m_LiteralValues, convertdouble(l_double))`, specifically in `convertdouble(l_double)`. [`push_back_a` requires](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/classic/doc/predefined_actors.html) that its second argument be a reference to be stored in a "policy holder actor" so using the function call there causes the error. If you don't need to store `l_double` and were simply using it as a temporary, one way to accomplish what you want is creating your own phoenix function that behaves similarly to `push_back_a` as explained [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/classic/doc/phoenix.html)(full example [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/classic/example/fundamental/stuff_vector.cpp)).
You define the phoenix function like this:

```
struct push_back_impl
{
    template <typename Container, typename Item>
    struct result
    {
        typedef void type;
    };

    template <typename Container, typename Item>
    void operator()(Container& c, Item const& item) const
    {
        c.push_back(convertdouble(item));
    }
};

function<push_back_impl> const push_back = push_back_impl();
```

and then define your rule like this:

```
rule<> alternative3 =   +( real_p[push_back(var(result.m_LiteralValues),arg1)] >>  str_p(",") );
```

Full compilable code(change the for loop to show the results if you can't/don't want to use c++11):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix1_functions.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix1_primitives.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::spirit::classic;
using namespace phoenix;

std::string convertdouble(const double& d)
{   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<d;
    return ss.str();
}

struct push_back_impl
{
    template <typename Container, typename Item>
    struct result
    {
        typedef void type;
    };

    template <typename Container, typename Item>
    void operator()(Container& c, Item const& item) const
    {
        c.push_back(convertdouble(item));
    }
};

function<push_back_impl> const push_back = push_back_impl();

struct Results
{
    std::vector<std::string> m_LiteralValues;
};


int main()
{
    Results result;
    char const* test="2.5,3.6,4.8,";
    rule<> alternative3 =   +( real_p[push_back(var(result.m_LiteralValues),arg1)] >>  str_p(",") );

    if(parse(test,alternative3,space_p).full)
    {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
        for(auto& str :result.m_LiteralValues)
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "failure" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;                       
}
```